# Future inside guard

Tags: scala, future, guard

Is there any way to wait for the Future `f` to be completed inside the guard block? 
Not inside the `case` block or outside the `Try` block.

```
import scala.util.Try
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Main extends App {
  val f = Future {
    Thread.sleep(999999)
    true
  }

  Try (1) match {
    case x if f => println("Waited for future")  // Here
    case _ => println(":(")
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `case x if f` ?

Comment: It's a guard: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need these additional imports:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await
```

You can do it like this:

```
case x if Try(Await.ready(f, 2 minutes)).isSuccess => println("Future completed")
```

Comment: Yes, that is how waiting for a future works. You can reduce the duration to let's say 1 second to reduce the amount of time the main thread is blocked.

Comment: It's not cool I guess. I am looking something like `map` or `onSuccess` maybe

Comment: Then I don't understand what you want to do. Please elaborate.

Comment: No need more. I figured out this case. Thank you